# ¿Cómo añadir texto al principio de un texto existente con jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un conjunto de elementos `<a>`que tienen, por ejemplo:

```
<a class="menu-elemento" href="#">Hola</a>
<a class="menu-elemento" href="#">Mundo</a>
```

Y quiero agregarles texto al ya existente. Para que queden de esta manera:

```
<a class="menu-elemento" href="#">*** Hola</a>
<a class="menu-elemento" href="#">*** Mundo</a>
```

Donde los `***` representan el texto que quiero insertar. ¿Cómo puedo conseguir esto utilizando jquery o javascript nativo?

Comment: tiene que tener el mismo id o el mismo class name?

Comment: Te recomiendo que leas sobre como manejar el DOM con javascript [aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) te dejo una buena introducción. Ya luego, facilítate la vida con jQuery, pero no cometas el mismo error que yo, primero aprende javascript bien y luego entra en jQuery. Te será más fácil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como tenes dos elementos con la misma clase, para seleccionar cada uno podes usar el selector [eq](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/), por otro lado para insertar el texto podes usar la función [prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

```js
$(".menu-elemento:eq(0)").prepend("### "); //primero
$(".menu-elemento:eq(1)").prepend("*** "); //segundo

//En el caso que quieras poner el mismo texto a todos los elementos sin diferenciarlos
$(".menu-elemento2").prepend("&&& "); //segundo
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="menu-elemento" href="#">Hola</a>
<br>
<a class="menu-elemento" href="#">Mundo</a>
<br>
<a class="menu-elemento2" href="#">Hola</a>
<br>
<a class="menu-elemento2" href="#">Mundo</a>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. No conocía la función prepend.

Answer (score 3):

Si el texto es el mismo para todos, puedes usar lo que dice @LeonardoCabré aunque no es necesario hacerlo uno por uno. Solo lo haces usando la clase `menu-elemento` que asumo es la misma que comparten los elementos del grupo:

```js
$(".menu-elemento").prepend("TEXTO ");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="menu-elemento" href="#">Hola</a>
<br>
<a class="menu-elemento" href="#">Mundo</a>
```

Si lo quieres en JavaScript puedes usar [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) para obtener los elementos por su clase, iterar sobre ellos y agregarles el texto al inicio:

```js
var elementos = document.getElementsByClassName('menu-elemento');
for (var i=0; i < elementos.length; i++) {
    elementos[i].innerText = 'TEXTO ' + elementos[i].innerText;
}
```

```html
<a class="menu-elemento" href="#">Hola</a>
<br>
<a class="menu-elemento" href="#">Mundo</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes usar selectores para poder acceder a los elementos del DOM, existen diferentes tipos de selectores están los de clases CSS, identificador, por etiqueta, etc, de esa manera puedes acceder a los atributos de cada , te pongo un ejemplo dinámico usando el valor de una caja de texto, para ponerlo al inicio de cada

```js
$(document)
  .ready(function(){
    var $myInput = $('#myInput');
    // accedemos a todos las etiquetas que tengan la clase menu-elemento
    var $a = $('.menu-elemento'); 
  
    // cada que el input cambie su valor
    $myInput.keyup(function(){
      $a.prepend($myInput.val());
    })
  })
```

```html
<a class="menu-elemento" href="#">Hola</a>
<a class="menu-elemento" href="#">Mundo</a>


<input type="text" id="myInput">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

si eres nuevo te recomiendo que empieces por aprender como acceder a elementos dentro del DOM

Comment: Tu respuesta funciona, pero considero que le estas añadiendo mas complejidad de la necesaria :S solo con poner $('.menu-elemento').prepend('*** ');  deberia funcionar, recorrer los valores esta de mas.

Comment: @CristinaCarrascoAngulo tienes mucha razón, editare la respuesta para no generar confusiones, gracias por la observación